# How to change scroll direction in Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

This tab:

[image]

For some reason has reverse scroll whilst Console and every other place in dev tools has normal scroll (scroll down it will go down, scroll up and it will go up). Is it possible to make Network scroll also natural?

Answer (score 0):

using Edge Dev Preview Version 88.0.685.3 - I see the same. It feels very strange, so it must have appeared with a version upgrade lately. On Edge Version 86.0.622.63 it works correctly, same as on Chrome Version 86.0.4240.183